# Check value of callBackContext

Tags: android, cordova, callback

I want to check null or not null sent value callbackcontext from JavaScript to Android on Android site on

> execute()

method, but i don't know how can i check this? I can't use equals null! Do you know how can check this on Android side?

I want use this, because some my methods use callback and another methods not use this!

Thanks for your advises.

EDIT:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if(callbackContext==null)
         //do something...
    else
         //do another work...

}
```

I want check callbackContext is null or not like above code!

Comment: Can you show us some code as to how you do and what you do ? And what is the execute method ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I send a part of my code.

Comment: Nobody here that answer to my question? Please help me!

Comment: Hi, Can you show us exec call from your javascript. 
 "because some my methods use callback and another methods not use this" by this do you mean you will be not passing success and error handler from javascript exec call?? as for as I know, callbackContext won't be null in both cases, either you send callbacks or not.